# Pandas add columns based on dates

Tags: python, pandas

A person or 'worker' can have multiple position assignments (jobs) over time. Each position assignment has a validfrom and valid to date. I'm trying to obtain the FullTimeEquivalency for a worker on the 16th of each month.

DataFrame df3 contains a list of persons
DataFrame df4 contains a list of positions
df3.RecId_x equals df4.Worker and should be used to establish a link between the two dataframes.

```
df3.columns 
Out[81]: Index(['PersonnelNumber', 'Person', 'RecId_x', 'NameAlias'], dtype='object')

df4.columns
    Out[82]: 
    Index(['Worker', 'Position', 'ValidFrom_ass', 'ValidTo_ass', 'Description',
           'FullTimeEquivalency', 'Department'],
          dtype='object')
```

Example:

```
df3.head(2)
Out[84]: 
  PersonnelNumber      Person     RecId_x             NameAlias
0          2  5637162883  5637144780       Mr A
1          6  5637162893  5637144784  Mr B



df4[df4['Worker']==5637144780]
Out[86]: 
         Worker    Position       ValidFrom_ass         ValidTo_ass  \
793  5637144780  5637158077 2017-01-01 01:00:00 2017-02-20 00:59:59   
875  5637144780  5637158076 2017-02-21 01:00:00 2020-01-10 00:59:59   

    Description  FullTimeEquivalency  Department  
793    Position1                  1.0  5637336774  
875    Position2                  0.9  5637336774
```

**Goal:**

my goal would to add to df3 columns 'jan_fte','feb_fte',...
listing the fte for that month for each worker.

My attempt:

```
df3['Jan_fte']= df4[(df4['Worker']==df3.RecId_x) & (df4['ValidFrom_ass'] <= '2017-01-16') & (df4['ValidTo_ass'] >='2017-01-16')]

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

df3
NameAlias, jan_fte, feb_fte, mar_fte, ..

Mr A, 1.0 , 1.0 , 0.9,..

jan_fte has 1.0 as Mr A was assigned at 16-01-2017 to Position 1, with FullTimeEquivalency 1.0
feb_fte has 1.0 as Mr A was assigned at 16-02-2017 to Position 1, with FullTimeEquivalency 1.0
mar_fte has 0.9 as Mr A was assigned at 16-03-2017 to Position 2, with FullTimeEquivalency 0.9

reproduction data:

```
import pandas as pd
#df3 dict as df8
df8 = pd.DataFrame({'NameAlias': {0: 'Mr A', 1: 'Mr B'},
 'Person': {0: 5637162883, 1: 5637162893},
 'PersonnelNumber': {0: '2', 1: '6'},
 'RecId_x': {0: 5637144780, 1: 5637144784}})

#df4 filtered on worker 5637144780 dict as df9:
df9 = pd.DataFrame({'Department': {793: 5637336774, 875: 5637336774},
 'Description': {793: 'Position 1', 875: 'Position 2'},
 'FullTimeEquivalency': {793: 1.0, 875: 0.90000000000000002},
 'Position': {793: 5637158077, 875: 5637158076},
 'ValidFrom_ass': {793: pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 01:00:00'),
  875: pd.Timestamp('2017-02-21 01:00:00')},
 'ValidTo_ass': {793: pd.Timestamp('2017-02-20 00:59:59'),
  875: pd.Timestamp('2020-01-10 00:59:59')},
 'Worker': {793: 5637144780, 875: 5637144780}})
```

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve isn't clear - could you add a few rows of made-up data with the calculation done manually so that everyone knows exactly the desired outcome?

Comment: Added example as requested

Comment: How is `FullTimeEquivalency` calculated?

Comment: df4.FullTimeEquivalency is a given value.

Comment: df4.FullTimeEquivalency is a given value. In order to obtain this value for each worker in df3 for each month, I would expect to first take the df3.RecId_x (i.e. 5637144780) , then filter df4.Worker on this value. This leads to two position records. Depending on the month i.e. January, it should further filter df4 on a record valid on 16-01-2017 (Position 1) For this record take the FullTimeEquivalency .  Potentially I should look at join or apply function?

Comment: I'm onto something:

mydate = '2017-01-16'

df8['jan_fte'] = df8['RecId_x'].apply(lambda x: df9[(df9['Worker']== x) & (df9['ValidFrom_ass'] <= mydate) & (df9['ValidTo_ass'] >= mydate)].FullTimeEquivalency)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve the desired result.

```
## SETUP DATA TO REPRODUCE:
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
#df3 dict as df8
df8 = pd.DataFrame({'NameAlias': {0: 'anonymous',
  1: 'anonymous',
  2: 'anonymous',
  3: 'anonymous',
  4: 'anonymous'},
 'Person': {0: 5637163197,
  1: 5637198703,
  2: 5637336887,
  3: 5637191544,
  4: 5637163123},

 'RecId_x': {0: 5637144954,
  1: 5637145759,
  2: 5637163507,
  3: 5637145684,
  4: 5637144903}})

#df4 as df9:
df9 = pd.DataFrame({'FullTimeEquivalency': {202: 1.0,
  252: 0.80000000000000004,
  255: 0.80000000000000004,
  258: 0.80000000000000004,
  354: 1.0,
  386: 1.0,
  639: 0.80000000000000004,
  690: 0.0,
  696: 1.0,
  731: 1.0},
 'ValidFrom_ass': {202: Timestamp('2015-11-01 01:00:00'),
  252: Timestamp('2010-01-01 01:00:00'),
  255: Timestamp('2010-01-02 01:00:00'),
  258: Timestamp('2016-01-01 01:00:00'),
  354: Timestamp('2010-01-01 01:00:00'),
  386: Timestamp('2010-09-21 02:00:00'),
  639: Timestamp('2015-01-01 01:00:00'),
  690: Timestamp('2014-04-01 02:00:00'),
  696: Timestamp('2015-01-26 01:00:00'),
  731: Timestamp('2017-05-01 02:00:00')},
 'ValidFrom_pos': {202: Timestamp('2015-11-01 01:00:00'),
  252: Timestamp('2010-01-01 01:00:00'),
  255: Timestamp('2010-01-02 01:00:00'),
  258: Timestamp('2016-01-01 01:00:00'),
  354: Timestamp('2010-01-01 01:00:00'),
  386: Timestamp('2010-09-21 02:00:00'),
  639: Timestamp('2015-01-01 01:00:00'),
  690: Timestamp('2014-04-01 02:00:00'),
  696: Timestamp('2015-01-26 01:00:00'),
  731: Timestamp('2017-05-01 02:00:00')},
 'ValidTo_ass': {202: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59'),
  252: Timestamp('2010-01-02 00:59:59'),
  255: Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:59:59'),
  258: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59'),
  354: Timestamp('2010-09-21 01:59:59'),
  386: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59'),
  639: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59'),
  690: Timestamp('2015-01-26 00:59:59'),
  696: Timestamp('2017-05-01 01:59:59'),
  731: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59')},
 'ValidTo_pos': {202: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59'),
  252: Timestamp('2010-01-02 00:59:59'),
  255: Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:59:59'),
  258: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59'),
  354: Timestamp('2010-09-21 01:59:59'),
  386: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59'),
  639: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59'),
  690: Timestamp('2015-01-26 00:59:59'),
  696: Timestamp('2017-05-01 01:59:59'),
  731: Timestamp('2154-12-31 00:59:59')},
 'Worker': {202: 5637163507,
  252: 5637144903,
  255: 5637144903,
  258: 5637144903,
  354: 5637144954,
  386: 5637144954,
  639: 5637145684,
  690: 5637145759,
  696: 5637145759,
  731: 5637145759}})

print('--Dataframe df8--')
print(df8)
print('--Dataframe df9--')
print(df9)

#SOLUTION:

cols = list()
dr = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', 
                   end='2017-12-31',
                   freq='MS'
                   ).shift(15, freq='D')

for date in dr:
    format_date = date.strftime('%b')
    cols.append(format_date)
    for wkr in df8.RecId_x.values:

        try:
            val = df9[(df9['Worker']==wkr) & 
                      (df9['ValidFrom_ass'] <= date) & 
                      (df9['ValidTo_ass'] >= date) & 
                      (df9['ValidFrom_pos'] <= date) & 
                      (df9['ValidTo_pos'] >= date)].FullTimeEquivalency.sum()

        except:
            val = 0.0

        df8.loc[df8.RecId_x==wkr,format_date] = val
df8['mean_fte'] = df8[cols].mean(axis=1)

print('--Desired output:--')
print(df8)
```